# How do I setup SharpRepository to work with AutoFac & Entiry Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, autofac, sharp-repository

I have installed

```
SharpRepository.EfRepository
SharpRepository.Ioc.Autofac
SharpRepository.Repository
```

and I have added this code to setup Autofac as instructed by the Autofac documentation:

```
    void SetupAutofac()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Get your HttpConfiguration.
        HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

        // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
```

but the SharpRepository getting started guide doesn't help me with the Autofac --> EF --> SharpRepo glue stuff as it's oriented towards StructureMap. Please advice!

(I'd like to avoid putting stuff in Web.config if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install the SharpRpository.Ioc.Autofac NuGet package, if you haven't.

Then you will call

```
builder.RegisterSharpRepository()
```

in order to tell Autofac how to handle an IRepository.

Then to tell SharpRpository to use Autofac when it needs EF you will need to call

```
RepositoryDependencyResolver.SetDependencyResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

That should do it.